# Awk function in Unix script returning wrong Sum of the column

Tags: awk

I have a script using awk to sum a column. File has 30 million records and actual total is

13367024114246662

but with awk getting

13367024114231658

Not sure what is causing the discrepancy.

Command used:

```
awk -v var=$1 -F”^G” ‘{total += $var} END {printf(“%28d/n”,total)}’ $file | sed ‘s/^[ ]*//‘ | sed ‘s/ [ ]*$//‘
```

Record looks like this

```
2008328721^G226^G16^G^G^G^G20230627^G0
```

Tried different ways of awk but still discrepancy.

Comment: Is that a literal `^G` or does it indicate `Ctrl+G` ?

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#FP-Math-Caution

Answer (score 2):

If using `GNU awk` and it's been compiled with the MPFR and MP libraries you may be able to use the `-M/--bignum` flag.

On my system:

```
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2, PMA Avon 8-g1, (GNU MPFR 4.2.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
^^^^^^^                                     ^^^^            ^^

$ man gawk
...
       -M, --bignum
              Force arbitrary precision arithmetic on numbers. This option has
              no effect if gawk is not compiled to use the GNU  MPFR  and  GMP
              libraries.  (In such a case, gawk issues a warning.)
...
```

Using janm's example:

```
$ awk -M 'BEGIN { print 13367024114231658 + 1}'
13367024114231659

$ awk --bignum 'BEGIN { print 13367024114231658 + 1}'
13367024114231659
```

Comment: MPFR is on parole so YMMV coming to rely on it, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/MPFR-On-Parole.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `awk` for integer arithmetic, use it only to extract the first field and then pipe to `bc`:

```
awk -F '\\^G' '{print "a+=" $1} END {print "a"}' "$file" | bc
```

Or with `sed` instead of `awk`:

```
sed 's/\^G.*//;s/^/a+=/;$s/$/;a/' "$file" | bc
```

Answer (score 1):

The awk numeric type is floating point, which is not precise. The number is large enough to show imprecision in that type.

For example, on my machine here:

```
janm@Laptop: ~ $ awk 'END { print 13367024114231658 + 1}' < /dev/null
13367024114231660
janm@Laptop: ~ $
```

The accumulated error from each addition shows in your result.

Comment: Thanks , unfortunately -M and —bignum not working , any other ways to handle this. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at @RenauldPacalet 's answer. It solves the problem quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you Janm for your response, just one query , from your experience using bc could affect the performance? Thanks

Comment: @VenuVakul There isn't anything there that should make performance bad. Most of the time is likely to be in the string processing, not in the addition in bc.